# iOS paint features to my app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add a drawing feature to my app. I have two UIImageViews... the bottom one contains a picture, let's say a photograph, and the second one on top of it is the one I want to paint on.

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIView *tappedView = [gesture.view hitTest:[gesture locationInView:gesture.view] withEvent:nil];

    CGPoint currentPoint = [gesture locationInView:_paintOverlay];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_paintOverlay.frame.size);
    [_paintOverlay.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _paintOverlay.frame.size.width, _paintOverlay.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5, 5);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
   _paintOverlay.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    NSLog(@"Touch event on view: %@",[tappedView class]);
}
```

This simply isn't working. I can't find any tutorials to help me with this, the one I found (where I derived this code from) wasn't so understandable.

Comment: You can hardly expect to paint with taps, surely. Is this an exercise in pointilisme? In any case, please explain what "isn't working" even means. What were you hoping for, and what actually happens?

Comment: Isn't working meant there is no painting done on the UIImageView. I was hoping to create a basic paint app where a user taps-moves-lifts finger and there are paints drawn accordingly.

Comment: Well, a tap gesture recognizer doesn't detect "moves"; in fact, it will reject that as not being a tap at all. So the issue is possible that you are making the wrong gesture. To be recognized by a tap gesture recognizer, your gesture needs to be a simple tap! That's why it is called (get this) a _tap_ gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, such as it is, works well enough. I didn't have an `image` so I omitted that, but by supplying values for `brush` and so forth I found that tapping on the view made a line appear:

[image]

It's a terrible way to paint (paint by tapping? only making lines coming from a single point???), but it does make lines.

However, I naturally configured my tap gesture recognizer and views correctly. You don't say what you did, so who knows? Did you hook the tap gesture recognizer to its action handler? Did you add it to the view? Did you remember to turn on the view's `userInteractionEnabled`? Did you tap as your gesture? A lot of things can go wrong; you need to debug, see what's happening, and tell us more about it.

Comment: I suppose tapping isn't the way to go. I didn't know what gesture to use to work with Tap-Slide-Lift Finger .... Can you show me how to modify my code to fit that scenario? Of course with the mod you made to supply brush and omit image.

Comment: No, that's way too broad and would be a completely different question (or would require at least a modicum of thought or research at your end). I answered _this_ question. You claimed your code doesn't work. I correctly countered that by demonstrating that it does.

Comment: Can you show me the code you ended up using that works?

Comment: I told you: It is exactly your code except that I put in some numbers where you are showing only names of variables (`brush`, `red`, `green`, `blue`).

Comment: I can't manage to replicate your screenshot doing so. Can you paste me the code?

Comment: The shoe is on the other foot. I told you what I did. _You_ are the one who asked the question. _You_ have not revealed sufficiently what _you_ did. _You_ post the project. Put it on github and I'll be glad to fix it to prove that your code can be made to respond to a tap.

Answer (score -1):

try with touches methods instead of tap gesture since one can move the fingers around to draw, touches will be good to implement.
refer the sample at: https://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit